# XcodeでMGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.と表示されてしまいます

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift4

XcodeをVersion 10.0 (10A255)にバージョンアップしました。SwiftのプラグラムをiPhone8 Simulatorで実行すると以下のエラーが表示されるようになりました。また、iPhone X/XR/XS/XS MaxのSimulatorでは以下のエラーは表示されません。なにか、地図関係か何かに変化があったのでしょうか？　ご存知の方があれば　ご教授ください。

2018-09-19 14:41:26.945506+0900 VoiceToDo1[13120:353456] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

同内容のスレッドが、AppleのDeveloper Forumsにありました。

[What is MGIsDeviceOneOfType](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103753)

残念ながらAppleの技術者からのコメントはありませんが、「新しいSDKにありがちな、フレームワークの内部メッセージ(フレームワーク開発者が仕込んだデバッグメッセージ)だろう。今の所実害はないし無視して大丈夫そうだ。」と言うところに落ち着いたようです。

本家StackOverflowのスレッドがこちら。

[Xcode Error on Simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50701321/6541007)

回答ではなくコメントに「シミュレータじゃなくデバイスで実行(Xcode10正式版、10A255のこと)したらメッセージは出ない」と言う報告もあるので、やはり無視しても問題ないのではないかと思われます。

何やら「自分はこうしたら解決した」と言うやり方を書いている方もいるのですが、それが正しい解決方法だと言う確証がないので、たまたまいろんな要因が重なってその時点で解決できたように見えただけ、と言う可能性も高そうです。

下手に真似すると自分のプロジェクトを壊してしまう可能性もあるので、メッセージが出てくる以外に実害が無いのでしたら、無視した方が良いのではないかと思います。(AppleのSDKの一部には、そんなメッセージが出るものが時々あります。)

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。該当のメッセージが出るのを無視します。